# "node_modules/minimatch/dist/cjs/index"' has no exported member 'IOptions'

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a TypeScript project to run on a Firebase function.

Here is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2017"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["dist", "node_modules"]
}
```

When I build (npm run build, which runs tsc)

I got the error

> node_modules/@types/glob/index.d.ts:29:42 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/opt/workspace/personal/kioskify-backend/functions/node_modules/minimatch/dist/cjs/index"' has no exported member 'IOptions'.

> 29     interface IOptions extends minimatch.IOptions {

EDIT: The error occurs in other modules. Full output:

```
npm run build

> build
> npm run lint && tsc


> lint
> eslint --fix .

node_modules/@types/glob/index.d.ts:29:42 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/opt/workspace/personal/kioskify-backend/functions/node_modules/minimatch/dist/cjs/index"' has no exported member 'IOptions'.

29     interface IOptions extends minimatch.IOptions {
                                            ~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/glob/index.d.ts:75:30 - error TS2724: '"/opt/workspace/personal/kioskify-backend/functions/node_modules/minimatch/dist/cjs/index"' has no exported member named 'IMinimatch'. Did you mean 'Minimatch'?

75         minimatch: minimatch.IMinimatch;
                                ~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/rimraf/index.d.ts:33:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/opt/workspace/personal/kioskify-backend/functions/node_modules/glob/dist/mjs/index"' has no exported member 'IOptions'.

33         glob?: glob.IOptions | false | undefined;
                       ~~~~~~~~


Found 3 errors in 2 files.

Errors  Files
     2  node_modules/@types/glob/index.d.ts:29
     1  node_modules/@types/rimraf/index.d.ts:33
```

And other similar errors, what can be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `rimraf` solved the issue.

Answer (score 16):

Upgrade rimraf, glob, and minimatch to latest. Remove the `@types` packages for all three. Then it'll work fine.

These three are all written in ts now, the `@types` packages are causing the problem.

Source: I wrote all three of these.

Comment: I had the same issue with `@types/gulp` installed.  Removing it allowed `gulp` to work again.

Comment: What else other than deleting it manually can be done? Should a PR with their removal be submitted to the DefinitelyTyped repo or is there some package.json workaround? Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean, remove types? the types are dependencies, I want to define everything installed in my package.json and not manually edit the package-lock.json or write scripts to delete from node_modules.

Comment: any clarification on this @isaacs?

Comment: Oof yeah quite annoying the way this was done, we have lots of dependent packages on @types/glob that are now broken =(. This may not have been a BC break in isolation but definitely in the wider ecosystem.

Comment: These are dependancies of other packages I have installed, how do remove these when my dependancies depend on them?

Comment: Type definitions in your package.json are only dev dependencies that are needed, if the package/module they are for does not ship with any. You can remove them at any time and there shouldn't really be another package that has them as runtime dependency. Since all 3 mentioned packages in the answer come now with their own type definitions it is no longer necessary to import the separate ones (which probably got out of sync, hence the error). I had a `@types/glob` left over (I don't use glob in that project) and after removing that the error disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

Downgrading the `rimraf` package to version `^3.0.2` fixed the issue for me.

`npm i rimraf@^3.0.2`