# Firebase deploy error : has no exported member 'IOptions', has no exported member 'IOptions'

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, package.json

Trying to deploy  some previous working cloud functions with "Firebase deploy" and having following error linked to dependency "rimraf" :

```
node_modules/@types/glob/index.d.ts:29:42 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/.../functions/node_modules/minimatch/dist/cjs/index"' has no exported member 'IOptions'.

29     interface IOptions extends minimatch.IOptions {
                                            ~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/glob/index.d.ts:75:30 - error TS2724: '"C:/Users/.../functions/node_modules/minimatch/dist/cjs/index"' has no exported member named 'IMinimatch'. Did you mean 'Minimatch'?

75         minimatch: minimatch.IMinimatch;
```

New installed environment on a new laptop using Windows 11 :

```
npm: '10.4.0',
node: '20.11.0',
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm run lint && tsc",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "20"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js": "^3.3.42",
    "@types/stripe": "^8.0.417",
    "firebase-admin": "^12.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.7.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^13.3.0",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.2",
    "stripe": "^14.17.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@stylistic/eslint-plugin-ts": "^1.6.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8.55.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

There are already some discussions going on with the package writer involved but the solution still seems confusing and not working :

["node_modules/minimatch/dist/cjs/index"' has no exported member 'IOptions'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75890950/node-modules-minimatch-dist-cjs-index-has-no-exported-member-ioptions)

https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf/issues/264

```
npm explain rimraf dependencies
```

gives the following :

I am surprised as i got the Firebase packages to the latest version on a issue which seems to be 1 year old.

```
rimraf@3.0.2
node_modules/rimraf
  rimraf@"^3.0.0" from firebase-tools@13.3.0
  node_modules/firebase-tools
    firebase-tools@"^13.3.0" from the root project
  rimraf@"^3.0.2" from flat-cache@3.2.0
  node_modules/flat-cache
    flat-cache@"^3.0.4" from file-entry-cache@6.0.1
    node_modules/file-entry-cache
      file-entry-cache@"^6.0.1" from eslint@8.56.0
      node_modules/eslint
        dev eslint@"^8.55.0" from the root project
        peer eslint@"^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || >=8.0.0" from @eslint-community/eslint-utils@4.4.0
        node_modules/@eslint-community/eslint-utils
          @eslint-community/eslint-utils@"^4.4.0" from @typescript-eslint/utils@7.0.1
          node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/utils
            @typescript-eslint/utils@"7.0.1" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@7.0.1
            node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
              dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^7.0.1" from the root project
          @eslint-community/eslint-utils@"^4.4.0" from @typescript-eslint/utils@7.0.1
          node_modules/@typescript-eslint/type-utils/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/utils
            @typescript-eslint/utils@"7.0.1" from @typescript-eslint/type-utils@7.0.1
            node_modules/@typescript-eslint/type-utils
              @typescript-eslint/type-utils@"7.0.1" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@7.0.1
              node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
                dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^7.0.1" from the root project
          @eslint-community/eslint-utils@"^4.4.0" from @typescript-eslint/utils@6.21.0
          node_modules/@typescript-eslint/utils
            @typescript-eslint/utils@"^6.21.0" from @stylistic/eslint-plugin-ts@1.6.2
            node_modules/@stylistic/eslint-plugin-ts
              dev @stylistic/eslint-plugin-ts@"^1.6.2" from the root project
          @eslint-community/eslint-utils@"^4.2.0" from eslint@8.56.0
        peer eslint@">=8.40.0" from @stylistic/eslint-plugin-js@1.6.2
        node_modules/@stylistic/eslint-plugin-js
          @stylistic/eslint-plugin-js@"1.6.2" from @stylistic/eslint-plugin-ts@1.6.2
          node_modules/@stylistic/eslint-plugin-ts
            dev @stylistic/eslint-plugin-ts@"^1.6.2" from the root project
        peer eslint@">=8.40.0" from @stylistic/eslint-plugin-ts@1.6.2
        node_modules/@stylistic/eslint-plugin-ts
          dev @stylistic/eslint-plugin-ts@"^1.6.2" from the root project
        peer eslint@"^8.56.0" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@7.0.1
        node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
          dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^7.0.1" from the root project
        peer eslint@"^8.56.0" from @typescript-eslint/utils@7.0.1
        node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/utils
          @typescript-eslint/utils@"7.0.1" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@7.0.1
          node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
            dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^7.0.1" from the root project
        peer eslint@"^8.56.0" from @typescript-eslint/parser@7.0.1
        node_modules/@typescript-eslint/parser
          dev @typescript-eslint/parser@"^7.0.1" from the root project
          peer @typescript-eslint/parser@"^7.0.0" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@7.0.1
          node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
            dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^7.0.1" from the root project
        peer eslint@"^8.56.0" from @typescript-eslint/type-utils@7.0.1
        node_modules/@typescript-eslint/type-utils
          @typescript-eslint/type-utils@"7.0.1" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@7.0.1
          node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
            dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^7.0.1" from the root project
        peer eslint@"^8.56.0" from @typescript-eslint/utils@7.0.1
        node_modules/@typescript-eslint/type-utils/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/utils
          @typescript-eslint/utils@"7.0.1" from @typescript-eslint/type-utils@7.0.1
          node_modules/@typescript-eslint/type-utils
            @typescript-eslint/type-utils@"7.0.1" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@7.0.1
            node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
              dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^7.0.1" from the root project
        peer eslint@"^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0" from @typescript-eslint/utils@6.21.0
        node_modules/@typescript-eslint/utils
          @typescript-eslint/utils@"^6.21.0" from @stylistic/eslint-plugin-ts@1.6.2
          node_modules/@stylistic/eslint-plugin-ts
            dev @stylistic/eslint-plugin-ts@"^1.6.2" from the root project
        peer eslint@">=5.16.0" from eslint-config-google@0.14.0
        node_modules/eslint-config-google
          dev eslint-config-google@"^0.14.0" from the root project
        peer eslint@"^2 || ^3 || ^4 || ^5 || ^6 || ^7.2.0 || ^8" from eslint-plugin-import@2.29.1
        node_modules/eslint-plugin-import
          dev eslint-plugin-import@"^2.29.1" from the root project
  rimraf@"^3.0.0" from tmp@0.2.1
  node_modules/tmp
    tmp@"^0.2.1" from firebase-tools@13.3.0
    node_modules/firebase-tools
      firebase-tools@"^13.3.0" from the root project
    tmp@"^0.2.1" from protobufjs-cli@1.1.1
    node_modules/protobufjs-cli
      protobufjs-cli@"1.1.1" from google-gax@3.6.1
      node_modules/@google-cloud/pubsub/node_modules/google-gax
        google-gax@"^3.6.1" from @google-cloud/pubsub@3.7.5
        node_modules/@google-cloud/pubsub
          @google-cloud/pubsub@"^3.0.1" from firebase-tools@13.3.0
          node_modules/firebase-tools
            firebase-tools@"^13.3.0" from the root project
```