# User has no exported member 'IOptions' 'IMinimatch'

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

Recently I have encountered a very strange error within my `nodejs, typescript` application.

I have installed Firebase most recently and after that whenever I am trying to build or run the application I get the following error:

```
node_modules/@types/glob/index.d.ts:29:42 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/ahmad/ahmad/api/node_modules/minimatch/dist/cjs/index"' has no exported member 'IOptions'.

29     interface IOptions extends minimatch.IOptions {
                                            ~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/glob/index.d.ts:75:30 - error TS2724: '"/home/ahmad/ahmad/api/node_modules/minimatch/dist/cjs/index"' has no exported member named 'IMinimatch'. Did you mean 'Minimatch'?

75         minimatch: minimatch.IMinimatch;
                                ~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/rimraf/index.d.ts:33:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/ahmad/ahmad/api/node_modules/glob/dist/commonjs/index"' has no exported member 'IOptions'.

33         glob?: glob.IOptions | false | undefined;
                       ~~~~~~~~


Found 3 errors in 2 files.

Errors  Files
     2  node_modules/@types/glob/index.d.ts:29
     1  node_modules/@types/rimraf/index.d.ts:33
```

Now, the issue is I have never seen `glob` and `rimraf` ever and I am not even sure what is going on that is causing this issue.

My node version is: **v20.11.1**

I have seen [**This Stackoverflow Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75890950/node-modules-minimatch-dist-cjs-index-has-no-exported-member-ioptions) but it didn't clear out anything for me.

Comment: `npm install @types/minimatch`?